# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem in an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller:

```
public ActionResult Product()
{
    return View(db.GetEntity(1).ToList());
}
```

This is my procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEntity]  
    (@EntityTypeID INT) 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Entity 
    INNER JOIN EntityType ON Entity.EntityTypeID = EntityType.EntityTypeID 
    WHERE EntityType.EntityTypeID = @EntityTypeID
```

This is my error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TelepatyWebsitedbModel.GetEntity_Result'. A member of the type, 'EntityTypeID1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the C# that you run to execute that SQL statement. The error implies the problem is in how that's working not any of this.

Comment: Update your complex type. And see whether your columns and the properties used match.

Comment: @War `db.GetEntity(1)` seems to be the C# call to the stored procedure, right ?

Comment: db.GetEntity(1) seems to be the C# call to the stored procedure, right ? Yes

Comment: You're not sharing enough information with us. Are you using EF? if so then tag your question and show what you have in your model.

Comment: EF to my knowledge does not have a GetEntity(key) method by default, yes this is the call to a method that does that, but no this is not the code that ultimately tells EF to go to the DB. I would expect something like Db.Foos.Find(id) or something and thus this sproc isn't needed, it's like this guy is reinventing the built in functionality for some reason which is why I asked for more information.

Comment: Gut feeling, he's using ADO.Net (but not EF) and mapping with raw SQLCommand and SQLDataReader objects but I would need to see that code to understand what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are reinventing the wheel.
Consider using an ORM (Object Relationship Manager), such frameworks are designed to handle tasks like this for you.

For example: Entity Framework is a popular choice for .Net based solutions that is useful for helping new users get their heads around database modelling and entities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application